# What's the best way for me to refresh the same image, and restart the animation of a gif/apng without reloading the entire page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image doesn't update, it's the same exact image in every way. I'd just like for an animated image i've created to cycle only once to refresh itself, or even reload after some information is changed triggering an if-statement.

I've looked up a lot of answers and most of them seem like I need to add a random ?blahblah to cache bust the browser into thinking it's a new image and redownload

how can I add a timestamp to the end of

```
 background-image: url('imgur.com/blah.png?timestamphere');
```

Answer (score 0):

use given variable for timestamp

```
var timestamp= new Date().getTime().toString();
var dynUrl='imgur.com/blah.png?'+timestamp;
 document.getElementById("yourelementid").style.backgroundImage = "url("+dynUrl+")";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a DOM method should trigger a re-render, but this applies to a img src, not a background-image.  (One thing to consider with using background-images is that you can't easily add an 'alt' tag for non-sighted users or users who don't load images)

```
document.getElementById('myImg').setAttribute('src', '/myimg.jpg')
// setAttribute is a DOM method, so the browser should be notified that the DOM has changed.
```